# Открытие второго окна (приложения) с помощью кнопки

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qt-designer

У меня есть **2** кода с интерфейсами приложений.

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы когда в приложении **untitled.py** нажималась кнопка `PushButton` (при этом пароль и логин должны быть верными), открывалось другое приложение **2.py**.

Если логин и пароль неверные ничего не должно происходить.

[image: Окно через которое должно открываться другое окно]

[image: окно которое должно открываться]

**2.py** (мессенджер, файл для запуска):

```
import sys
from messenger import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):          # +  Ui_MainWindow
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)           #команда для активирования переноса текста через кнопку
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.on_button_click)    # <<---<   enter click    

    def on_button_click(self):
        message = self.lineEdit.text()                          #команда переноса текста
        self.lineEdit.clear()                                     # +++
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(message)            


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

**messenger.py** (код дизайна для мессенджера):

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(865, 516)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.plainTextEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(9)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.plainTextEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.plainTextEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(16)
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(font)
        self.plainTextEdit.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 20px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(254, 254, 254);")
        self.plainTextEdit.setReadOnly(True)
        self.plainTextEdit.setObjectName("plainTextEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.lineEdit.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.lineEdit.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.lineEdit.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("border-radius: 11px;\n"
"background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(1)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.pushButton.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.pushButton.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Arial")
        font.setPointSize(10)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0, y1:0.562, x2:1, y2:0.563, stop:0 rgba(53, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(42, 255, 177, 255));\n"
"border-radius: 11px;\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:hover {\n"
"    background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0, y1:0.562, x2:1, y2:0.563, stop:0 rgba(47, 227, 227, 255), stop:1 rgba(36, 223, 155, 255));\n"
"}\n"
"QPushButton:pressed {\n"
"    color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0, y1:0.562, x2:1, y2:0.563, stop:0 rgba(41, 198, 198, 255), stop:1 rgba(30, 190, 132, 255));\n"
"")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Messenger"))
        self.plainTextEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "  Тут будут сообщения..."))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", " Введите ваше сообщение"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Отправить сообщение"))
```

**untitled.py** (окно логина, файл для запуска)

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from design2 import *


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)     

    def onClicked(self):                                                      
        if self.lineEdit.text() != '123' or self.lineEdit_2.text() != '1234':
#                msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(self, 'Error', 
'Неправильный логин или пароль')
            messagebox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoIcon,
                "Ошибка!",
                "<p style='color: black;'> Неправильный логин или пароль. </p>",
                parent=None,
            )
            messagebox.move(self.pos().x()+350, self.pos().y()+200)
            messagebox.setIconPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("12.png").scaled(40, 40, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            messagebox.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            messagebox.setStyleSheet(
                """
                QMessageBox {
                    font: HelveticaNeueCyr 16px;         
                    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
            
                }         
                """
            )


            messagebox.exec_()
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'waiting...', 'Добро пожаловать!')  # + None


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**design2.py** (код дизайна для логина):

```
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(400, 600)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 600))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(400, 600))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(8)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        MainWindow.setFont(font)
        MainWindow.setWindowOpacity(1.0)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: qlineargradient(spread:pad, x1:0.011, y1:1, x2:1, y2:0, stop:0 rgba(182, 29, 212, 255), stop:1 rgba(48, 7, 182, 255));")
        MainWindow.setTabShape(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.Rounded)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 400, 201, 71))
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.OpenHandCursor))
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;\n"
"background-color: qlineargradient(spread:repeat, x1:0, y1:0.545, x2:1, y2:0.563, stop:0 rgba(53, 255, 255, 255), stop:1 rgba(42, 255, 177, 255));")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 200, 261, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        self.lineEdit.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;")
        self.lineEdit.setMaxLength(100)
        self.lineEdit.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 290, 261, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(22)
        font.setItalic(False)
        font.setUnderline(False)
        font.setStrikeOut(False)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.lineEdit_2.setFont(font)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
"border-radius: 30px;\n"
"\n"
"")
        self.lineEdit_2.setMaxLength(12)
        self.lineEdit_2.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.lineEdit_2.setCursorPosition(0)
        self.lineEdit_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.lineEdit_2.setDragEnabled(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setReadOnly(False)
        self.lineEdit_2.setClearButtonEnabled(True)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 90, 181, 101))
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font.setPointSize(35)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 360, 201, 16))
        font.setFamily("HelveticaNeueCyr")
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        ont.setPointSize(10)
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.PreferAntialias)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 360, 16, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(alpha 0.5);\n"
"color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Вход"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войти"))
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите логин"))
        self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите пароль"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Войдите"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Максимальная длина пароля - 12"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "*"))
```

Comment: импортируйте побочное окно в основной файл и в нужный момент вызовите его - `nameOfYourClass().show()`

Comment: @finally можете обьяснить по-подробнее как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я отметил места, где вам надо сделать правки.

**untitled.py**

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from design2 import Ui_MainWindow

from main_messenger import MessengerApp                                 # + импорт


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)     

        self.exampleApp = MessengerApp()                                # + создаем экэемпляр


    def onClicked(self):                                                      
        if self.lineEdit.text() != '123' or self.lineEdit_2.text() != '1234':
            messagebox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(
                QtWidgets.QMessageBox.NoIcon,
                "Ошибка!",
                "<p style='color: black;'> Неправильный логин или пароль. </p>",
                parent=None,
            )
            messagebox.move(self.pos().x()+350, self.pos().y()+200)
            messagebox.setIconPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("im.png").scaled(40, 40, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatio))
            messagebox.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)
            messagebox.setStyleSheet(
                """
                QMessageBox {
                    font: HelveticaNeueCyr 16px;         
                    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);

                }         
                """
            )


            messagebox.exec_()
        else:
            msg = QtWidgets.QMessageBox.information(None, 'waiting...', 'Добро пожаловать!')  # + None

            self.hide()                             # + закрыть окно
            self.exampleApp.show()                  # + показать новое окно


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

---

**main_messenger.py**

```
import sys
from messenger import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

# Внимание !!! имя класса ExampleApp используется в untitled.py 
#class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):   
class MessengerApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):           # MessengerApp  
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setupUi(self)
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_button_click)       
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.on_button_click)   

    def on_button_click(self):
        message = self.lineEdit.text()                              
        self.lineEdit.clear()                                       
        self.plainTextEdit.appendPlainText(message)            


if __name__=="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MessengerApp()                                          # MessengerApp
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @imapw_ добавил `self.hide()  # + закрыть окно`